# What is an easy way of percentage calculation in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table named "Categories". I am trying to get percentage of each category as as final table.

```
Category         TOTAL   
Category_x       5   
Category_y       10  
Category_z       20  
Category_a       30  
Category_b       40
```

Expected Table

```
Category         TOTAL    Overall_Percentage
Category_x       5        4.76
Category_y       10       9.523
Category_z       20       19.047
Category_a       30       28.57
Category_b       40       38.09
```

My Code:

```
SELECT Category, TOTAL, 100*(TOTAL/SUM(TOTAL)) AS Overall_Percentage
FROM Categories
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag.  It seems unlikely that you would choose BigQuery by accident.

Answer (score 5):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT Category, TOTAL,
       (TOTAL * 100.0 / SUM(TOTAL) OVER ()) AS Overall_Percentage
FROM Categories
```